# How do you define a mongoDB mongoose schema for a dynamic key dictionary?

Tags: mongodb, dictionary, dynamic, database-schema, mongoose-schema

I have a MongoDB collection `users` where I want to store a dictionary with dynamic keys. I want `users` to look like this within MongoDB:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5a9f5b3400e2f61a0c5f449b"
    },
    "profile": {
        "votes": {
            dynamicKey1Here: {
                constantKey: 'value',
                constantKey2: 'value2'
            },
            dynamicKey2Here: {
                constantKey: 'value',
                constantKey2: 'value2'
            },
            // more dynamic keys here...
    }
}
```

But I don't know how to define my schema. So far I have:

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
    profile: {
        votes: {DynamicKeyEntry}
    }
});
```

So how would I define the schema for `DynamicKeyEntry`?

```
const DynamicKeyEntry = new Schema(
    // HOW DO I DEFINE DYNAMIC KEYS?
);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use `aray` then it's better approach for storing and fetching data appropriately for ex:

```
 votes: { type: Array }
```

Now you can store multiple objects in `votes` as your requirement

Answer (score 1):

Because you have mentioned you are using mongoose, you could also use a Map or the Mixed type.
The Map type lets you set dynamic keys and still enforce some schema for the values:

```
votes: {
      type: Schema.Types.Map,
      of: new Schema(
        {
          constantKey: {
            type: Schema.Types.String,
            required: true,
          }
        }
      )  
...
```

The Mixed type gives you full control, but you want to validate the data properly on application side, otherwise you may end up in a mess.

```
votes: {
   type: Schema.Types.Mixed,
}
```